# Updating a JSP with messages received in Java (writing a messenger client)

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, iframe, listener

this is my first question here - hope I'll get started on a positive note.

**Refrasing** (since I am still stuck):
I am writing a IM client via the XMPP protocol to connect to a [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) server. For this I am using the [Smack API](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/). There are two ways of checking if new messages have been received:

- registering a listener with the XMPP connection, [addListener](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPConnection.html#addPacketListener(org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener,%20org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter)). The downside here is that I can't make changes to the JSP page inside the listener (only final variables are allowed inside an inner class).

  defining a packet collector and [polling for new results](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/PacketCollector.html#nextResult()). I want to avoid polling too often so that's why I am waiting for a new message when there is one. Also, how would the JSP/Javascript look in this case? as one does not know the time interval to refresh the iframe where the messages are displayed.

So the bottom line here would be receiving messages without constant polling. I would also like to stick to the Smack API as I see it pretty well documented. My problem lies more in the JSP department. Any expertise on this would really help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if thats the best way to write a client side listener.

I would suggest using **AJAX**, in that way you make all your work on the server side, and an Ajax component keeps polling the data from the server.

Comment: Actually I am using Ajax here in the way I am filling up the div with the messages that I receive. As for polling for data - the API that I'm using does not support that, which makes sense to me, as when you're connected to a IM server, you are the one that gets the messages. But maybe I misunderstood you, can you be more concrete?

Comment: I agree with medopal and go with an AJAX solution, creating a separate page to act as a service which is polled using JavaScript function from setTimeout(). Whenever polled I would have the page return a JOSN object with the last records up to a given ID or timestamp for an elegant and robust solution. Unfortunately you are stuck with polling in practice as keeping a streaming connection open in JS is not really practical (technically possible, but requires advanced ninja skills to implement in a robust way due to varying browser/proxy/web filter software timeout limits).

Comment: The polling practice is indeed the bottleneck to a good approach. But will keep in mind the JSON way of doing it though. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A small note on your problem description: your Listener don't have to be a inner class. (But that might not help you at all)

Comment: Hmm, how can you go around implementing the PacketListener[1] interface then?

[1]http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/PacketListener.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). Maybe it can help or at least give you some ideas. Check the *Implementations* and *Alternatives* sections.

Cheers